# arquillian-gwt eclipse export of war fails due to access denied

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Running GWTTestCase using arquillian with jboss-as-managed.  Get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jun 21, 2013 11:57:31 AM org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer startInternal
INFO: Starting container with: ["C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java", -Xmx512m, -XX:MaxPermSize=128m, -ea, -Djboss.home.dir=C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log, -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties, -Djboss.modules.dir=C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules, -Djboss.bundles.dir=C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bundles, -jar, C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar, -mp, C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules, -jaxpmodule, javax.xml.jaxp-provider, org.jboss.as.standalone, -server-config, standalone.xml]
11:57:31,623 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:57:31,795 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:57:31,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
11:57:32,436 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
11:57:32,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:57:32,436 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
11:57:32,452 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
11:57:32,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
11:57:32,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
11:57:32,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:57:32,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
11:57:32,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
11:57:32,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:57:32,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
11:57:32,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:57:32,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:57:32,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:57:32,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
11:57:32,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:57:32,659 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
11:57:32,893 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--<localhost>-8080
11:57:32,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on / 127.0.0.1 :4447
11:57:32,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on / 127.0.0.1 :9999
11:57:32,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
11:57:32,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:57:33,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http:// 127.0.0.1 :9990
11:57:33,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 1630ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
Compiling com.gwt.app.SampleContainerJUnit
11:57:40,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content\b6\29d9e93447ce9c24539027d891ae9b1dc4220c\content
11:57:40,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "arquillian-service"
11:57:40,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.arquillian-service" is using a private module ("org.jboss.as.jmx:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:57:40,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.arquillian-service" is using a private module ("org.jboss.as.server:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:57:40,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.arquillian-service" is using a private module ("org.jboss.as.osgi:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:57:40,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.arquillian-service" is using a private module ("org.jboss.jandex:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:57:40,489 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.arquillian-service" is using a private module ("org.jboss.osgi.framework:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:57:40,599 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "arquillian-service"
Jun 21, 2013 11:57:40 AM org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.JdkZipExporterDelegate$1 call
WARNING: Exception encountered during export of archive
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open file war\com.gwt.app.SampleJUnit\gwt
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.FileAsset.openStream(FileAsset.java:68)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.StreamExporterDelegateBase.processNode(StreamExporterDelegateBase.java:227)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.AbstractExporterDelegate.processNode(AbstractExporterDelegate.java:105)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.AbstractExporterDelegate.doExport(AbstractExporterDelegate.java:95)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.StreamExporterDelegateBase.access$001(StreamExporterDelegateBase.java:50)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.StreamExporterDelegateBase$1.call(StreamExporterDelegateBase.java:121)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.StreamExporterDelegateBase$1.call(StreamExporterDelegateBase.java:116)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.JdkZipExporterDelegate$1.call(JdkZipExporterDelegate.java:124)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.exporter.zip.JdkZipExporterDelegate$1.call(JdkZipExporterDelegate.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: war\com.gwt.app.SampleJUnit\gwt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.FileAsset.openStream(FileAsset.java:66)
    ... 13 more

11:57:41,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment arquillian-service in 8ms
11:57:41,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014901: Content removed from location C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content\b6\29d9e93447ce9c24539027d891ae9b1dc4220c\content
11:57:41,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS018558: Undeployed "arquillian-service"
```

Comment: @Deployment
 public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
  return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
      .addClass(Greeter.class)
      .addClass(GreetingService.class)
      .addClass(GreetingServiceImpl.class)
      .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
 }

Comment: Could this simply be an ACL issue my windows 8 permissions?  As far as I can tell, the folders involved allow full permissions.